# Ejecutar javascript desde el backend de c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con algo que necesito hacer, es que quiero que salga una alerta despues de ejecutar un metodo, les dejo mi codigo que según debe invocar la alerta pero no lo hace, y de paso la alerta que deberia mostrar

Este es el metodo detras del boton

```
protected void btn_registrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Page.IsValid)
        //{
            try
            {
                LlenarDatos();


                al_dao.agregarAlumno(al_bo);
                tutor_dao.agregarTutor(tutor_bo);
                al_dao.relacionarAlumnoTutor(altutor_bo);

                btn_subirimg.Visible = false;
                btn_registrar.Visible = false;

                string javaScript = "MostrarMensaje();";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script", javaScript, true);
            }
            catch
            {
                
            }
        //}

    }
```

Y este es mi codigo javascript de la alerta

```
<script>

$(function showContent() {
    
        Command: toastr["success"]("Datos guardados con exito!", "Validando")

        toastr.options = {
            "closeButton": false,
            "debug": false,
            "newestOnTop": false,
            "progressBar": true,
            "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
            "preventDuplicates": true,
            "onclick": null,
            "showDuration": "300",
            "hideDuration": "1000",
            "timeOut": "5000",
            "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
            "showEasing": "swing",
            "hideEasing": "linear",
            "showMethod": "fadeIn",
            "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        }
   
});
```

Comment: Supongo que deberías ejecutar `showContent();` pero en c# tienes `"MostrarMensaje();`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así  mediante una evaluación directa, pero requiere que
1. Evaluación directa de expresiones:

```
Console.WriteLine(ScriptEngine.Eval("jscript", "MostrarMensaje();"));
```

Este otro ejemplo también es útil;

```
using (ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine("jscript"))
{
  ParsedScript parsed = engine.Parse("function MostrarMensaje(x){return x + 1 ;}");
  Console.WriteLine(parsed.CallMethod("MostrarMensaje", 100));
}
```